# How to maintain Listbox Item order into DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, listbox

I have a listbox and two buttons, "Move up" and "Move Down". After changing the order of the items in the listbox, I want to export that listbox items as a DataGridView columns maintaining same order.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on web or windows?

you can read items of listbox into an array or list object then read one bye one and add to grid view cols.